# How do I find the properties available from a powershell command?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to find what the possible columns or elements are from the get-service command. I am mostly interested in finding the log on as value a service runs under, but it'd be nice to know how to find others when the need arises.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `Get-Member` cmdlet - `gm` in short

```
Get-Service | gm
```

Coming to `Log On As`, I think `Get-Service` ( or rather the `[ServiceController]` type) 
does not expose it. You can use WMI though:

```
gwmi win32_service | select name, startname
```

Comment: That works, but do you know how I could find the "log on as" value of a service?

Comment: @Bob - you could use `Get-WmiObject win32_Service| Select-Object Name, StartName`

Comment: you can also filter the get-member down using -MemberType. I like to do that so I can quickly find just the properties or methods available. [Get-Member -MemberType Property].